# Get Original Referrer URL from Google Search with PHP?

Tags: php, google-search-console

I am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`, to getting  Referrer URL.

When I typed in Google search box the `q='some text'`

```
`https://www.google.com.pk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=some text%2Ftestbulkresponse&oq=some text%2Ftestbulkresponse&gs_l=hp.3...15460.24280.1.25007.30.30.0.0.0.0.325.7136.2-27j3.30.0...0.0...1c.1.8.hp.dAvuch3bBg4&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44697112,d.ZWU&fp=980e418276b62e8c&biw=1366&bih=595`
```

but when I get this URL on my website using as  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

the `q=null` like this

```
`http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bulkresponse.com%2Ftestbulkresponse%2Fdashboard.php&ei=r9NbUfv7GcjaOYDdgKgC&usg=AFQjCNF9U_DpJEwupZ0ZLPbjWJ6DQLWZcA&bvm=bv.44697112,d.ZWU`.
```

So I am unable to get searched keywords in Google, what should I can do to get searched keywords?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google removes the search query for HTTPS connections and logged users so the only way to know the search query is using Google Analytics

> When you search from https://www.google.com, websites you visit from our organic search listings will still know that you came from Google, but won't receive information about each individual query.

http://googleblog.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html
http://analytics.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/making-search-more-secure-accessing.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $queries);

echo $queries['q'];
```

References:

http://php.net/parse_url

http://php.net/parse_str

Answer (score 1):

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(strstr($ref, "google.com")){
  //echo $ref;  
  $regex ='/q=(.+?)&/';
  preg_match($regex, $ref, $query);
  echo $query[1];
 }
```

it doesn't work everytime, especially now with their updates. I  get " &esrc=s " reported a lot.