# Filter elements on website according to web search

Tags: jquery, django

I'm developing an application with Django 1.8.

And my client asked me if it was possible to show some elements of the website, according to how the guest user is searching on search engines.

For example, I have element A, B and C.

If user searched the word 'security', and clicked the website link based on that search, then I'll show elements A,B,C, in that order.

If user looked for 'ip-camera', and clicked the website link based on that keyword, then I'lll show elements on this order: B,C,A, or maybe even hide one of them.

Maybe a filter based on google analytics or something like that?

Is this possible this way? If so, then is there any tutorial on this kind of feature? I honestly can't figure out where to look at.

I hope I've explained myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll want to read this.  It seems this isn't 100% feasible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781034/how-to-get-original-referrer-url-from-google-search-with-php

Comment: Do you have a way to track what the user is doing? If not, what you are describing is not possible.

Comment: Hi, no, actually no, because the user doesn't need to be logged in on the platform, so I guess it's not possible